# EntityFieldQuery throws an error while using fieldCondition and addTag('node_access')

Tags: drupal-7

I use Drupal 7.
This code:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$resFirstName = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
            ->entityCondition('bundle', 'user')
            ->fieldCondition('field_user_first_name', 'value', $str, 'RLIKE')
            ->range(0, 15)
            ->addTag('node_access')
            ->execute();
```

when site's user **isn't Admin** throws the following error:
"PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'field_data_field_user_first_name0.nid' in 'where clause': SELECT field_data_field_user_first_name0.entity_type AS entity_type, ..."
If I remove `->fieldCondition('field_user_first_name', 'value', $str, 'RLIKE')` or `->addTag('node_access')` - no error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar case. I was able to solve it modifying the `fieldCondition` like this while retaining all other conditions and parameters:

```
  ->fieldCondition('field_user', 'first_name', $str, 'RLIKE')
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue.
I has node_access tag added to a query, I could not remove it since other
modules relied on it to influence site queries globally.
I had to add a fieldCondition, so in my case the solution was
$query->addMetadata('account', user_load(1));

https://www.drupal.org/node/997394#comment-5096664